# How to count MySQL array values in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count

How to count MySQL array values? 
For example, the below code

```
$get = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE uid='$id'");
while($comp = mysqli_fetch_array($db, $get)) {
$country = $comp['country'];
echo "$country<br>";
}
```

will give output country names in the table country as

```
India
India
Pakistan
India
United States
Japan
United States
United States
India
```

I want to count the number of times each country appears in the table and store the values as:

```
 ['Country', 'Counts'],
 ['India', 4],
 ['Pakistan', 1],
 ['United States', 3],
 ['Japan', 1],
```

Comment: you could use mysql `group by` clause

Comment: You are looking for `group by`, a fundamental part of SQL.  You should learn the basics of SQL if you want to use databases at all effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL should read as

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) as `count` FROM clicks WHERE uid='$id' GROUP BY `country`
```

Then you should be able to call the `count` paramenter:

```
while($comp=mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
    echo $comp['country'].': '.$comp['count'];
}
```

Side note: MySQL has been depricated. You should look to switch to **MySQLi** or **PDO**.